# What happens when we add Identity Providers in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-ad-b2c

I have created an Identity Provider in my Azure AD B2C for my Web Application with the help of this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-msa-app

I just wanted to know the back-end process which will be happen while adding Identity Provider in Azure AD B2C deeply.

Comment: Sorry, what's your question?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I didn't understand the Microsoft blog regarding Identity Provider. Can you please elaborate the concept,behind this Identity Provider

Comment: Gotcha.  Good question.  Can you update your question?

Comment: Please do clarify your question. Are you asking, "What is an Identity Provider?" If so, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_provider